# image_tag syntax with or without "" - with method - ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, image, syntax

To "" or not to "" - that is the question.

```
<%=   image_tag(@profile.image, :size => "80x80", :alt => "Picture") %>
```

or

```
<%=   image_tag("@profile.image", :size => "80x80", :alt => "Picture") %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `"@profile.image"` will put the `src` attribute equal to `@profile.image`, NOT the value of `@profile.image`.

Don't use the quotes, unless your image is called "@profile.image".

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself this questions: Do you ever quote variable's in any programming language? Probably not. Some languages handle variables inside of double quotes so that you can write a string like this: `"My name is <variable>"`. The other way to do it is `"My name is "+<variable>`

So basically no you do not want to quote `"@profile.image"`.

Comment: That's why I thought I should omit it, despite the fact that it worked with the quotes as well. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

If the image's filename is @profile.image, then use quotes. If @profile.image contains the name of the image file, don't.

Comment: They both seem to render the picture, I believe it is the latter. But I want to make sure this will always work. @profile is a method of one record in the db, not a filename

Comment: Fascinating. image_tag("@profile.image", :size => "80x80", :alt => "Picture") should produce <img src="/images/@profile.image" width="80" height="80" alt="Picture" /> -- I'm not sure how that works without string interpolation (image_tag("#{@profile.image}", [...]).